# Particular solution to nonhomogeneneous 2nd order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find a particular solution to this equation?

$$f''(x)+x^{-1}f'(x)-f(x)\left(1+x{}^{-2}\right)-Ax^{-2}=0$$

I know that the solution of the homogeneous equation (i.e. without the last term) is of the form

$$f(x)=c_{1}K_{1}(x)+d_{1}I_{1}(x)$$

but can't work out how to construct a particular solution. Variation of parameters? Thanks!

Comment: Variation of parameters should work. You might try some identity involving Bessel functions, orthogonality and $x^{-2}$.

Comment: @Pragabhava Could you expand on that please?

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: Variation of parameters will work directly; you need to know $W(K_1,I_1)$ (which I think simplifies easily by a Bessel function identity), and you need to integrate $\frac{K_1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{I_1}{x^2}$.

Comment: @Pragabhava They can be imposed at the end (at least modulo singularities).

Comment: OK, but I have to warn you that in my experience as student and teacher, it's a very undidactic way to learn (and work with) odes and pdes. A differential equation is not properly defined without boundary conditions and a domain of integration.

Comment: @Pragabhava A linear ODE on a fixed domain can be usefully defined without requiring boundary conditions. The solutions form an affine space, which is the reason we seek particular solutions and homogeneous solutions separately when we attempt to identify general solutions. When it is possible to identify general solutions, this is a good technique for solving IVPs/BVPs, since adjoining the initial or boundary conditions then amounts to solving a system of linear equations. Specific boundary conditions are more important in PDE for many reasons, but the problem at hand here is an ODE.

Comment: @Ian The reason we look for homogeneous and particular solutions separately is _linearity_ (the affine space wording is a fancy way of stating this). Didactically, it is a very bad idea to work without bcs: students have a hard time understanding why different bcs lead to different Green functions, what to do with singularities, separation of variables, solvability conditions, etc. This problems grow as they think pdes can be treated the same way, when they have nonmixed bcs and when they work with any kind of nonlinearity.

Comment: @Pragabhava I don't think the correction of my wording was necessary, yes the solution structure arises from linearity, but I was focusing on the solution structure in particular.

Comment: @Pragabhava I'm torn between these two sides. At the elementary level, there is a lot of power in finding *all* solutions to the differential equation and identifying the solution that you actually want by solving an algebraic equation. This is especially true when the algebraic equation is "nice", such as in the linear case. Yet the issues that you've described do create problems if one gets used to thinking about the problem this way. However, should we think of these as central, or as "technical issues" to be handled after one has a grasp on whatever generalities are available?

Comment: @Pragabhava Also, after one has learned it all, when we are faced with a problem like the OP, should we restrict attention to a problem with prescribed BCs, thus making our lives easier? Or should we just bite the bullet and solve the DE itself in general, worrying about BCs later? In a lot of the cases you're talking about, the latter isn't even possible, or if it is, it is *much* harder than solving the simple case that is of primary interest.

Comment: @Pragabhava But in this problem I don't think that is the case, since variation of parameters immediately writes down a particular solution and thus the general solution. (Sorry for the series of comments).

Comment: If that counts, anyway, I was looking for the general solution, without specified bcs. I know that one must be aware of its significance and that this cannot be done for pdes, etc. But in my specific case I want to keep the freedom to study different bcs.

Comment: @Ian I agree with all your concerns. In my experience, students tend to omit BCs because they don't understand their role and importance. That's why I'm so emphatic about them, specially on this site, where lack of context is almost a given. If this problem had arisen form a PDE on a cylinder, two out of three students wouldn't know what to do with the _missing_ boundary condition, and the implications on the eigenvalues, eigenfunctions, etc. All the fun starts when BCs are imposed :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have initial conditions at $x = a$ and your domain of integration is $x\in(a,b)$. The variation of parameters formula says that:
$$
f_p(x) = - A I_1(x)\int_a^x \frac{K_1(t) dt}{W(t) t^2} + A K_1(x)\int_a^x \frac{I_1(t)dt}{W(t)t^2},
$$
where $W(t)$ is thhe Wronskian of $K_1(t)$ and $I_1(t)$, which is<sup>[1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.28)</sup>
$$
W(t) = K_1(t)I_1'(t) - K_1'(t) I_1(t) = \frac{1}{t}.
$$

And so 
$$
f_p(x) = -A K_1(x)\int_a^x \frac{I_1(t) dt}{t} + A I_1(x)\int_a^x \frac{K_1(t)dt}{t}.
$$

which can, in turn, be explicitly written in terms of the Meijer G and the Generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: You wrote the coefficients of the homogeneous solutions in the particular solution but you neglected to multiply them by the homogeneous solutions themselves.

Comment: @Ian True. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: The minus sign is in front of the wrong term, I guess.

Comment: @usumdelphini Sorry about that. It has been corrected.